# Keycloak password blacklist doesn't work with special symbols

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a text file with blacklisted passwords and set up filename to Authentication -> Password Policy -> Password Blacklist in keycloak. If there's simple passwords like

```
password
admin
user
```

It works good - when I'm trying to change password I see this message `Error! Invalid password: password is blacklisted.`
But when I add more complex password to this list like `Music.1%` it doesn't work - I can change password to this.

Why does it work so and is there ways to blacklist similar passwords in file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Keycloak documentation one can read the following:

**Password Blacklist**

> This policy checks if a given password (converted to lowercase) is
> contained in a blacklist file, which is potentially a very large file.
> Password blacklists are UTF-8 plain-text files with Unix line endings
> where every line represents a blacklisted password. **All passwords in
> the blacklist must be lowercased to facilitate case-insensitive
> comparison.** The file name of the blacklist file must be provided as
> the password policy value, e.g.
> 10_million_password_list_top_1000000.txt. Blacklist files are resolved
> against ${jboss.server.data.dir}/password-blacklists/ by default. This
> path can be customized via the keycloak.password.blacklists.path
> system property, or the blacklistsPath property of the
> passwordBlacklist policy SPI configuration.

The reason why with the passwords "password", "admin", and "user" works whereas "Music.1%" did not is that the first three are in lower-case whereas the last one was not. It is not is the special symbol.